# Do std::array elements have to be reset?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

```
std::array<int,4> myInts;
std::array<bool,2> myBools;
```

Can the elements of `myInts` and `myBools` be assumed to be false and 0, or should I `fill` the arrays manually?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The elements will be set to random values, but you can make sure to value initialize them like this:

```
std::array<int,4> myInts{}; // all zeroes
std::array<bool,2> myBools{}; // all false
```

So the elements do not have to be reset, they can be initialized to certain values. You can also initialize elements to different values:

```
std::array<int,4> myInts{1,2,33,44};
std::array<bool,2> myBools{true, false};
```

If you have less elements than the size of the array in the initializer list, then the missing ones get zero initialized:

```
std::array<int,4> myInts{1,2}; // array contains 1,2,0,0
```

**Note** The standard specifies that `std::array` is an aggregate, and has some example code where it shows it implemented as having an array data member. It claims this is just to emphasize that the type is an aggregate, but if this implementation is used (and GCC uses it) then you would need an extra set of braces because you are initializing the array inside the `std::array`:

```
std::array<int,4> myInts{ {1,2,33,44} };
```

On the other hand, this case qualifies for brace elision, so the extra set of braces is not mandatory.

Comment: Would be a good addition to an answer, unfortunately you don't actually answer the question.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about the empty-list initialization.

Comment: @delnan very true. I have made it into an answer now.

Comment: `std::array` initialization requires a double set of braces ([unless you're using `=`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863319/stdarrayt-initialization))

Comment: @Prætorian well, I am still not 100% convinced about that one, and the standard seems a bit vague on the issue. I added a note about that.

Comment: @juanchopanza: The Standard is not vague on the issue. It is pretty much clear (see [my detail answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734861/when-can-outer-braces-be-omitted-in-an-initializer-list)). (well that doesn't mean that double set of braces is needed in your answer . +1 :-) ).

Comment: @Nawaz I read the relevant section and it didn't seem clear to me. I will read it again tomorrow with a fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: @juanchopanza: You can read the section **"More on braces and extra braces"** in my answer. That is the most relevant part.

Comment: @Nawaz I even left a comment on that answer :-) My point is that it isn't clear to me that `std::array` **has** to be implemented as holding an array.