# Why do I need a compound literal like temporary construction to initialise my std::array member?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, g++, compound-literals

Consider this minimal example:

```
#include <array>
struct X {
  std::array<int,2> a;
  X(int i, int j) : a(std::array<int,2>{{i,j}}) {}
  //                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^
};
```

According to [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8863355/430766) I shouldn't have to explicitly construct a temporary in this situation. I should be able to write:

```
  X(int i, int j) : a{{i,j}} {}
```

but this and several other (similar) versions I tried are all refused by my (admittedly quite old) g++ 4.5.2. I currently have only that one for experimentation. It says:

> `error: could not convert ‘{{i, j}}’ to ‘std::array<int, 2ul>’`

Is this a limitation of this compiler implementation or what's going on?

Comment: That's not a compound literal; C++ doesn't even have them!

Comment: Yes, your outdated GCC is the issue -- [works fine with 4.7.1](http://liveworkspace.org/code/af413b3d9b062ea32cd3dd7b3e3aff33).

Comment: I'd assumed he was talking about multicharacter literals, but there's none of those in this question either.

Comment: Yep, that's why C++ syntax and semantics are driving me nuts. Agreed to Mr Torvalds.

Comment: @eq-: It's not? Then it's a proper constructor? What do we call this, then. It is the default constructor to a temporary; Maybe there's a name for it.

Comment: @bitmask, it's a simple object construction (using the new C++11 brace syntax, combined with initializer lists). Can't remember any special name for it.

Comment: @eq-: I changed the title. Hope this is better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, as a lot of times, the compiler version. The following code works fine with GCC 4.7.1:

```
#include <array>

struct X{
  std::array<int, 2> a;
  X() : a{{1,2}} {}
};

int main(){
  X x;
}
```

[Live example.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/ccc92885d7384db48fec0999db97699a)

Comment: This was answered in the comments by ildjam.

Comment: @MattPhillips: Okay, and because I wrote my answer at the same time, I get a downvote? Sorry that I was a little bit slower with typing. Also, a question needs an answer to accept, not just a comment.

Comment: Just got to your comment now, sorry about that Xeo.  I should have looked at the timestamps and now my downvote is locked.  FWIW I made it up to you elsewhere. :)

Comment: @MattPhillips: You can make a stealth edit (as I just did, just removing / adding some whitespace) to make it unlocked again, for future reference. :)